# AWS EC2 p2.xlarge should have 61GiB memory but my code run out of RAM at about 11GB

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, amazon-ec2, instances

In the terminal I found some error like these:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats: 
Limit:                 11332668621
InUse:                 11332668416
MaxInUse:              11332668416
NumAllocs:                      13
MaxAllocSize:          11332445440
```

But the p2.xlarge instance should have 61GiB memory...
What is wrong here? Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [New P2 Instance Type](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-p2-instance-type-for-amazon-ec2-up-to-16-gpus/)

The **host memory** is **61GB** for `p2.xlarge` instance. The **GPU memory** is **12GB** and you exhausted your GPU memory.

[image]

Comment: But it really shouldn't. My model is pretty simple at this time...I will have to open an new topic on this tho.

Comment: Later I realized that the model is not that correct - the tensor graph still works but produce an unreasonably massive tensor, which exhausted all the memory.

Comment: @helloV can you please elaborate the difference between the host memory and the gpu memory?